# Custom @JsonProperty Annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

Consider the json schema:

```
{
    "type":"object",
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "required":false,
    "properties":{
        "inventory":{
            "type":"object",
            "required":false,
            "properties":{
                "count":{
                    "type":"number",
                    "required":false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When using jsonschema2pojo, this generates a corresponding java object. Extracted from this is the following declaration for count (full class below):

```
@JsonProperty("count")
private Double count;
```

```js
package com.test.json;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "count"
})
public class Inventory{

    /**
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("count")
    private Double count;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The count
     */
    @JsonProperty("count")
    public Double getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param count
     *     The count
     */
    @JsonProperty("count")
    public void setCount(Double count) {
        this.arpu = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, other);
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

If the JSON interface changes, and count becomes countOfItems, both the JSON property annotation, **AND** the java variable name change, which affects getters and setters:

```
@JsonProperty("countOfItems")
private Double countOfItems;

@JsonProperty("countOfItems")
public Double getCountOfItems()

@JsonProperty("countOfItems")
public void setCountOfItems(Double countOfItems)
```

I would like to be able to customise the generated class so that implementing java code didn't have to change, i.e.:

```
@JsonProperty("countOfItems")
private Double count;

@JsonProperty("countOfItems")
public Double getCount()

@JsonProperty("countOfItems")
public void setCount(Double count)
```

Is this kind of feature supported using JSON schema and jsonschema2pojo? I can't find any information on how to do this on the [json schema](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) or [jsonscema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Reference) documentation.

Obviously this could be achieved by hand crafting the java object, but I'd rather keep using generated classes.

Comment: This is unrelated to jsonschema. Json-schema does not specify how types must be created in programming languages. About your problem, the only possible solution I see is to generate the POJOs just once, and from there do manual changes to mappings to schema when this change. And I doubt there exist a general solution (in fact, the use of json-schema in this type-generation is very limited).